# How to avoid showing already-authorized to app dialog in Android Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

[image]

I'm getting a completely useless page when I use the Single Sign on for Facebook's Android SDK.

```
"You have already authorized app. Press "Okay" to continue.
```

This page would destroy user experience. How can I remove this screen?

Thanks in advance.

**Note: we won't see this issue If the FB app is installed in device. It will be raised only if the FB app is not available in device.**

Comment: It looks like this issue may have been around for a long time, check this post from 2010: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495845/how-to-avoid-already-authorized-in-android-facebook-sdk

Comment: I have the same problem does anyone find a solution for it ???

Comment: Nope :( ... That is happening for every application which uses the facebook sdk in client Android app. You can overcome this by developing facebook features in server app.

Comment: I had the same problem and found that if native FB app is not installed in device, 'already authorized' window shows up every time i post to FB and it gets resolved by installing the native FB app

Comment: @MandeepPasbola we wont get this issue If the FB app installed in device. It will be raised if the FB app is not available in device.

Comment: When I run my app on the emulator (FB not installed), I see this popup. But when I run it on my phone (FB app installed), I do not see it. Therefore its less of a problem than I initially thought.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the latest `Facebook SDK 3.6` I believe and have tested so far on *HTC One* & *Galaxy s3 mini*. This page does not display itself for me at any point. I followed the API guide here...

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

Here is the code aswell... perhaps this may help.

```
public class LoginHandlerFrag extends Fragment {

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";
    // private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                         Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container,
                false);

        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view
                .findViewById(R.id.authButton);

        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "user_location",
                "user_birthday", "user_likes", "user_photos"));
        authButton.setFragment(this);

        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        return view;
    }

    private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
        // Make an API call to get user data and define a
        // new callback to handle the response.
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session,
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                        // If the response is successful
                        if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                // profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
                            }
                        }
                        if (response.getError() != null) {
                            // Handle errors, will do so later.
                        }
                    }
                });
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
                                      Exception exception) {
        session = Session.getActiveSession();
        SharedPreferences storedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = storedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("userLoggedTracker", true);
        editor.commit();

        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
            makeMeRequest(session);
            editor.putBoolean("userLoggedTracker", false);
            editor.commit();
            getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
            editor.putBoolean("userLoggedTracker", true);
            editor.commit();
            getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a hint this is the fallback method with the webview. Please note the small x on the upper right. By the way today is the least version is 4.0.1 where this still happens for me.

Answer (score 1):

Before I used this code for Facebook logout :

```
if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
            return; // already logged out
        }

        new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest
                .Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

            }
        }).executeAsync();
```

After changed to this code `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` solved the issue.