# phonegap iOS facebook Re-Authentication issue

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

I am using Cordova 3.4.0 along with the official facebook connect plugin [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

The issue is that every time user opens the application. He/She has to press login and then it shows the "App already authorized screen" before the user is able to perform any action. How to prevent this addition of an action in the user flow?

[image: Screenshot Attached]

I read that it is basically because the access token isn't stored by the plugin. As a result this action needs to be taken again and again. So I have now stored access token using localstorage but unfortunately don't know how to go about using it.

```
FB.api('/me/friends?access_token="+access_token+"', { fields: 'id, name, picture' },
```

Using it in the manner above results in an error saying invalid oAuth access token. Even though I placed an alert before this line to ensure that access_token had a valid value. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciate.

Just to rephrase I don't want the user to be asked to press login button every time they open the application.

Comment: I think this is by design. It has been asked many a times before: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888582/facebook-login-give-me-already-authorized-this-app-without-automatic-returning-t), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725173/how-to-avoid-showing-already-authorized-to-app-dialog-in-android-facebook-sdk), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495845/how-to-avoid-already-authorized-in-android-facebook-sdk) and many other times...

Comment: Thank you for all those links. I have reach each one of them but none of them helps find a solution unfortunately. And as for design I understand that. But will storing the access token help? In case I want there to be a work around

Comment: That's what I said, that this is by design you cant do anything about it I guess