# Android Facebook "You have already authorised appname"

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-java-api

I have integrated the Facebook SDK into my Android app (authenticating to Firebase). I am requesting "email" and "public_profile" permissions. I am testing this on a phone without the Facebook app, so the following is happening in Chrome through facebook.com.

The first time the user clicks the LoginButton he is asked to accept permissions. After doing so he is returned to my app and authentication is successful.

After that, however, when the user clicks the LoginButton again, he is shown a screen saying "You have already authorised ..."

I want this step to be skipped ff the user already did authorised my app, but how?

Answer (score 0):

U can't , better way is to make first login from facebook ,then ask them to make login id and password for your app .don't make them login again with facebook

Comment: Okay, seems weird to me. Can you explain why this is not an option? Thanks

Comment: Loginbutton chages itself to logout from facebook once its been authorised. You will haveto define app's flow with facebook login screen to screen.Let's say if you want to lander user to diffrent screen you can pass intent in    onActivityResult method

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725173/how-to-avoid-showing-already-authorized-to-app-dialog-in-android-facebook-sdk

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at the following documentation page from Facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

You will find at the bottom of the page how to delete permissions for an User (Revoking Permissions). This can even executed when the User is not logged in.