# Android facebook authentication dialog issue

Tags: android

When login via facebook i am getting the a dialog with following text every time

### "You have already Authorize in the application"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I do not want that dialog.

Comment: Can't help it if a user has authorized an app once FB won't ask to do it again

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495845/how-to-avoid-already-authorized-in-android-facebook-sdk

Comment: I had the same problem and found that if native FB app is not installed in device, 'already authorized' window shows up every time i post to FB and it gets resolved by installing the native FB app

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook API will display this dialog. Nothing you can really do about that. 
Just change the time interval the dialog is shown and move on to the next step