# Login from facebook in android

Tags: android

I am able to successfully login to the app from Facebook. The only problem is when Facebook app is not installed on the device, after login it gives a message "You have already authorized 'app name'". Login functionality works fine if Facebook is installed on the device. How to get rid of this message?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495845/how-to-avoid-already-authorized-in-android-facebook-sdk) ?

Comment: Time it took me to find a duplicate : 3 seconds.

Comment: its common as you have already authorised with same login and app that's why you seeing this message. its not error or warning

Answer (score 2):

If the Facebook app is not installed in the device and you're using the Facebook SDK for Android, then the app will show you a WebView with the Facebook authentication dialog.

You're seeing that message ("You've already authorized this app"), because the profile you're using to login has already given you access to your app. To deauthorize an app you need to go to Facebook.com, click on the little arrow in the upper right corner, go to Settings > Apps and remove your app from the list.